# C# Entity Framework Grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a Schedule table with data as follows...

```
ScheduleID | CustomerID | SubdivisionID | LotNumber | ProductID | ProductDate
1            1            1               5555        1           11/7/2015
2            1            1               5555        2           11/8/2015
3            1            1               5555        3           11/9/2015
4            2            1               7777        1           11/7/2015
5            2            1               7777        2           11/8/2015
6            2            1               7777        3           11/9/2015
```

I need a C# Linq To Entities query that returns the data grouped by CustomerID, SubdivisionID, LotNumber with all the Product Dates in a row.

So for example, I need to see the data like this...

```
CustomerID | SubdivisionID | LotNumber | ProductDate1 | ProductDate2 | ProductDate3
1            1               5555        11/7/2015      11/8/2015      11/9/2015
2            1               7777        11/7/2015      11/8/2015      11/9/2015
```

I believe that involves some grouping and joining, but I am not too great with Entity Framework groups. What should my code look like here?

I'm thinking something along these lines...

```
var context = new ScheduleEntities();
from c in context.Schedule
where c.ProductID == 1 || c.ProductID == 2 || c.ProductID = 3
group c by new { c.CustomerID, c.SubdivisionID, c.LotNumber } into grouped
select new {
    CustomerID = grouped.Key.CustomerID,
    SubdivisionID = grouped.Key.SubdivisionID,
    LotNumber = grouped.Key.LotNumber,
    ProductDates = **some kind of List<> ??**
}
```

As you can see, I'm confused as to how I would get all of my product dates into my anonymous entity. What should I do?

Comment: Use a stored procedure.  Look into the PIVOT T-SQL command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use this `ProductDates = grouped.Select(p => p.ProductDate)`

Comment: I'd like to use linq method syntax rather than linq query syntax, you can rewrite this in query syntax, they are the same.

Comment: So simple, it seems like I should have thought of it myself. I guess I was having one of those mental blocks!

Comment: Just have a look at the struture of IGrouping you can find this solution.